# Problem getting Fedora to run in VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit, trying to get Fedora 18 64-bit to run in the Oracle VM VirtualBox.

I've got VirtualBox installed (via the .deb package available from the official site,) and I got the Fedora 18 64-bit DVD image downloaded. I then created a new virtual machine, with appropriate settings. When I try to boot the image, it displays a few options: "Install Fedora", "Test this media & install Fedora", and a "Troubleshooting" option.

I chose one of the installation options, and it went to a grey screen. I assumed it was just a loading screen, but it wouldn't stop. I let it stay on that screen for a few hours, then killed it. None of the other options yielded any different results.

Comment: This question has already been posted on Ask Ubuntu, and closed for being deemed off-topic. It would likely not be a good fit for a SE site about Fedora, so please don't migrate or close this. I don't want to be the victim of a game of ["Migration Hot Potato"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/).

Comment: When you create the VM, did you use Type=Linux and Version=Fedora (64 bit)?

Comment: It's totally on-topic here.

Comment: Have you tried adding "text" to the boot prompt, to force the [text mode installer](http://installer-land.blogspot.com/2012/10/text-mode-for-fedora-18.html)

Comment: @JohnSiu When I created it, I did choose Linux, Fedora, but there was no explicit 64-bit option.

Comment: @mattdm Okay, so I just press Tab and add `text` to the end of the command?

Comment: What version of virtualbox are you using?

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude: Um, I think press Esc, offhand. Maybe Tab. Then type `linux text` and Enter. (This will not be terribly pretty and will get you a minimal install, but should _work_.)

Comment: @mattdm Nope, that didn't work. Adding it to the end of the normal installation command just resulted in the normal grey screen, and running `linux text` as a command itself just gives me the menu I was already at.

Comment: @JohnSiu Version 4.2.6

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention: it starts off using a text-based installer: [imgur.com/0qFu57f](http://imgur.com/0qFu57f). I don't know how to get the GUI working.

Comment: Fedora 18 uses latest Gnome 3, and that one requires accelerated 3D graphics, with no excuses AFAIU. If the virtualization doesn't provide that, I'm afraid it won't work.

Comment: Would it be worth trying one of the Spins, such as the KDE Spin or the LXDE Spin? It's a pain to download a large DVD iso, but would one of the less resource-intensive DEs have a better chance of succeeding?

Comment: FWIW [another question on Fedora x64 live CD hanging at boot](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72112). As a workaround, I'd consider febootstrap.