# Fedora 18 Live CD is hanging on boot

Tags: fedora, boot, virtual-machine

When I boot up Fedora 18 (`Fedora-18-x86_64-Live-Desktop.iso`) in a Virtual Machine, I just get this screen:

[image: Fedora]

I've verified the SHA sum, and I've tried starting it up in "basic graphics mode", yet I still get the same problem.

That's all I get, there is nothing else.

What is wrong?

Comment: FWIW [another question on Fedora x64 live CD hanging at boot](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61784). As a workaround, I'd consider febootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

Turning off 3D acceleration in the VM's configuration will fix it.  There's a bug with some of the packages on the CD.  After installing to the VM and running updates you can turn 3D acceleration back on.

Here is the ask.fedoraproject link that I saw: https://ask.fedoraproject.org/question/10024/fedora-18-impossible-to-use-on-vmware-9/

and the bug report:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=903413

Cheers